# No output from hidden Div with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is the java script function.I want it to make the div "resultss" visible and show the output.

But it's not displaying results, php code is executed without errors. Whys is this not displaying any output.

I'm trying to append the results at the bottom of same page where user submits some data

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
var e = document.getElementById("resultss");
e.style.display = "block";
<?php

$format =  $_SESSION["ff"];
$ses_id = $_SESSION["id"];
$filena = $_SESSION["filename"];
//$pubquery = $_SESSION["pubquery"];
$result1 = shell_exec("C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Python27\PredictoR\Model_desc.py $format $ses_id $filena  2>&1");
$properties = explode(" ", $result1);
if($properties[0] == 1)
{
$property = "Substrate";
} else  {
$property = "Non-substrate";
}
$molwt = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $properties[1]));
$nhd = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $properties[2]));
$nha = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $properties[3]));
$logp = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $properties[4]));

?>

var molwt = <?php echo json_encode( $molwt); ?>;
var nhd = <?php echo json_encode( $nhd); ?>;
var nha = <?php echo json_encode( $nha); ?>;
var logp = <?php echo json_encode( $logp); ?>;
var property = <?php echo json_encode( $property); ?>;

document.getElementById('properties').innerHTML="Molecule is : "+property+"  \n\
<br/>Molecular weight is : "+molwt+" \n\
<br/>No. of hydrogen bond donors = "+nhd+"\n\
<br/>No. of hydrogen bond acceptors = "+nha+"\n\
<br/>Log P :  = "+logp+";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all close the script tag `</script>`
Secondly I can not see you calling your function `myFunction()`. Try calling it.
I hope it helps.

So you code should look something like:

```
<script>
  function myFunction()
  {
    var e = document.getElementById("resultss");
    e.style.display = "block";
<?php
$format = $_SESSION["ff"];
$ses_id = $_SESSION["id"];
$filena = $_SESSION["filename"];
//$pubquery = $_SESSION["pubquery"];
$result1 = shell_exec("C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Python27\PredictoR\Model_desc.py $format $ses_id $filena  2>&1");
$properties = explode(" ", $result1);
if ($properties[0] == 1) {
  $property = "Substrate";
} else {
  $property = "Non-substrate";
}
$molwt = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $properties[1]));
$nhd = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $properties[2]));
$nha = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $properties[3]));
$logp = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $properties[4]));
?>

    var molwt = <?php echo json_encode($molwt); ?>;
    var nhd = <?php echo json_encode($nhd); ?>;
    var nha = <?php echo json_encode($nha); ?>;
    var logp = <?php echo json_encode($logp); ?>;
    var property = <?php echo json_encode($property); ?>;

    document.getElementById('properties').innerHTML = "Molecule is : " + property + "  \n\
<br/>Molecular weight is : " + molwt + " \n\
<br/>No. of hydrogen bond donors = " + nhd + "\n\
<br/>No. of hydrogen bond acceptors = " + nha + "\n\
<br/>Log P :  = " + logp;

  }
  myFunction();
</script>
```

Comment: I missed <script/> tag while copying but it is there in my original code. And call myfunction() was linked to button onclick() which I have not mentioned here. @Om Prakash

Comment: I am not sure whether your php code is not providing any output or you are not being able to display the result. Better provide more code so that I can review.